# Get first and Last date of each unique element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :

| A-Party | Date & Time | IMEI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3022275 | 2021-05-01 7:20:05 | A |
| 3022275 | 2021-05-02 8:20:05 | A |
| 3022275 | 2022-08-01 6:20:05 | A |
| 3022275 | 2021-03-02 9:20:05 | B |
| 3022275 | 2021-09-01 6:20:05 | B |
| 3022275 | 2022-05-01 10:20:05 | B |

I want first and last date of every unique IMEI:

Output I want:

| A-Party | Total IMEI | IMEI | First Date | Last Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3022275 | 2 | A | 2021-05-01 7:20:05 | 2022-08-01 6:20:05 |
|  |  | B | 2021-03-02 9:20:05 | 2022-05-01 10:20:05 |

I can achieve this nested for loop, but if there is any pandas way of directly doing this, that might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use names aggregation with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `first` and `last` or `min` and `max`:

```
df = (df.groupby(['A-Party','IMEI'], as_index=False)
        .agg(**{'First Date':('Date & Time', 'first'),
                'Last Date': ('Date & Time', 'last')}))

df.insert(1,'Total IMEI', df.groupby('A-Party')['A-Party'].transform('size'))

print (df)
   A-Party  Total IMEI IMEI          First Date            Last Date
0  3022275           2    A  2021-05-01 7:20:05   2022-08-01 6:20:05
1  3022275           2    B  2021-03-02 9:20:05  2022-05-01 10:20:05
```

If need spaces (not recommended, because possible mixing numeric with strings `''`):

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(['A-Party','Total IMEI']), ['A-Party','Total IMEI']] = ''

print (df)
   A-Party Total IMEI IMEI          First Date            Last Date
0  3022275          2    A  2021-05-01 7:20:05   2022-08-01 6:20:05
1                        B  2021-03-02 9:20:05  2022-05-01 10:20:05
```

If need `MultiIndex`:

```
df = (df.groupby(['A-Party','IMEI'], as_index=False)
        .agg(**{'First Date':('Date & Time', 'first'),
                'Last Date': ('Date & Time', 'last')}))

df.insert(1,'Total IMEI', df.groupby('A-Party')['A-Party'].transform('size'))

df = df.set_index(['A-Party','Total IMEI','IMEI'])

print (df)
                                 First Date            Last Date
A-Party Total IMEI IMEI                                         
3022275 2          A     2021-05-01 7:20:05   2022-08-01 6:20:05
                   B     2021-03-02 9:20:05  2022-05-01 10:20:05
```

EDIT: Add [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to named aggregations:

```
df = (df.groupby(['A-Party','IMEI'], as_index=False)
        .agg(**{'Total IMEI':('IMEI', 'size'),
                'First Date':('Date & Time', 'first'),
                 'Last Date': ('Date & Time', 'last')}))
print (df)
   A-Party IMEI  Total IMEI          First Date            Last Date
0  3022275    A           3  2021-05-01 7:20:05   2022-08-01 6:20:05
1  3022275    B           3  2021-03-02 9:20:05  2022-05-01 10:20:05

df = df.set_index(['A-Party','Total IMEI','IMEI'])

print (df)
                                 First Date            Last Date
A-Party Total IMEI IMEI                                         
3022275 3          A     2021-05-01 7:20:05   2022-08-01 6:20:05
                   B     2021-03-02 9:20:05  2022-05-01 10:20:05
```

EDIT1:

```
df = (df.assign(dates = df['Date & Time'].dt.date)
        .groupby(['A-Party','IMEI'], as_index=False)
        .agg(**{'Total IMEI':('IMEI', 'size'),
                'No unique days': ('dates', 'nunique'),
                'First Date':('Date & Time', 'first'),
                 'Last Date': ('Date & Time', 'last')}))
print (df)
```

Comment: can't we show A-Party once and Total Imei once instead repeating in each row

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir - added to answer.

Comment: set A-Party and Total Imei as index

Comment: df.insert() Giving error:                                                                                                                      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: loc must be int

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir - sorry, it was first solution, answer was edited. By `df.insert(1,'Total IMEI', df.groupby('A-Party')['A-Party'].transform('size'))`

Comment: Modification:Column Total IMEI should contain sum of all rows of that Particular IMEI,Like IMEI 'A' has 3 rows and IMEI 'B' Also has 3 rows.Thye may have different rows.

Comment: I need one more column ,that tells how many days that particular imei was active like IMEI 'A' was active for 3 days.It should count a partucular date for once

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir - What means `how many days that particular imei was active` ? How is count it?

Comment: i mean count of unique dates(Skip time part) for particular imei.Like imei 'A' has 3 unique dates 2021-05-01 , 2021-05-02, 2021-08-01.So total days i would say 3 that particular imei was active

Comment: for a dataframe i used to achive like this len(df['Date & Time'].dt.date.unique())

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir - Can you check EDIT1?

Comment: for a dataframe i used to achieve like this len(df['Date & Time'].dt.date.unique()).Something similar in ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir - Do you think per groups? If yes, there is `EDIT1`

Comment: but for large data which contains duplicate dates like 2021-10-05 7:50:30, 2021-10-05 7:55:60 ,it gives all the count

Comment: @ZulqarnainSabir - it is weird, because added `.assign(dates = df['Date & Time'].dt.date)` for dates column and then `'No unique days': ('dates', 'nunique'),` create number of unique value by `dates` columns.

Comment: but it works anyway.Thanka

Answer (score 2):

I just form each column manually and then create the DataFrame.

```
A_Party = [df.iloc[0,0],'']
Total_IMEI = [df['IMEI'].nunique(),'']
IMEI = df['IMEI'].unique()
First_Date = df.groupby('IMEI')['Date & Time'].first()
Last_Date = df.groupby('IMEI')['Date & Time'].last()
col = ['A-Party','Total IMEI','IMEI','First Date','Last Date']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([A_Party,Total_IMEI,IMEI,First_Date,Last_Date]).T,columns=col)
df1
```

|  | A-Party | Total IMEI | IMEI | First Date | Last Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3022275 | 2 | A | 2021-05-01 7:20:05 | 2022-08-01 6:20:05 |
| 1 |  |  | B | 2021-03-02 9:20:05 | 2022-05-01 10:20:05 |